# Targeting an object's data within an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pull the data out of an object I stored with localStorage. I pull it out and parse it. I can target the localData object which returns my object

```
[
Object
body: "dog"
title: "title"
__proto__: Object
]
```

Then I target one down with localData[0] giving me:

```
Object {title: "title", body: "dog"}
```

However, I now want to target the value(s) of the key title and body.

Can't figure out how to target the object within the object.

Comment: You mean like `localData[0].title`?

Comment: i think you mean property of an object

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Was trying [title] and what not cause everywhere I was looking was saying .[key].